# The character 'ä' is read as 'õ' in the input parameters of the batch file

Tags: batch-file, encoding, cmd

My program has an input parameter to recognize which function it should run. I am preparing some *.bat* files now and one of the input parameters that my program can take is called "*hänvisnigskälla*" (Swedish for Reference Source).

The program works fine on my own computer but when I move it to the production server, I see that the program does not recognize the function name and reads it as "*hõnvisnigskõlla*". So the `ä` character is somewhere misread as `õ`.

I want to know the reason why this happens and whether there is a way on the server computer to fix it. Otherwise I should change my program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command line argument from batch file containing UTF-8 character causes trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782626/command-line-argument-from-batch-file-containing-utf-8-character-causes-trouble)

Comment: I will try it and come back to you, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is because the console has a different codepage than the rest of the system. Your Windows UI probably uses codepage 1252 as its default legacy codepage (where Unicode doesn't apply). This also applies to Notepad when saving a file and selecting "ANSI" as encoding.

The console on the other hand probably uses codepage 850 or 437, which has »õ« in the place where »ä« is in codepage 1252.

So either use »„« in Notepad (which is in the same place as »ä« in CP850), or use a different editor which allows you to save the file in OEM encoding, or use a different transliteration, even though it's not technically correct.

Another option is to use `chcp` to change the codepage of the console to 1252 as the first thing you do in your batch file. Then the output will be correct, too. But this changes the codepage of the console – a change that persists even after your batch file ends (if you call it in an interactive console session, at least). So I usually try to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks! I will try out your solution as soon as I connect to the server and will come back to you. Makes sense.

Comment: Although `„` and `ä` are both `0x84` encoded in extended ASCII (8bit), their Unicode values are `U+201E` and `U+00E4`, respectively in different code pages you have advised. Hence, we need to see how parameter e.g. `"hänvisnigskälla"` containing letters with diacritics is _used_ in a batch script. Text comparison? A part of a file path/name? Supplied to another executable (which one? what's inner encoding? what interface encoding?)? etc. [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) reasons My general advice: avoid of accented characters...

Comment: @Josef: Extended ASCII is a meaningless term. The Unicode code points have no relevance since we're talking about very specific code pages here. You simply have no way of working with multiple encodings in a batch file, so things are rather simple there.

Answer (score 1):

In addition of joey's answer, you could backup the chcp before change

```
@echo off
rem backup the current chcp
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:." %%x in ('chcp') do set cp=%%x

rem set your own
chcp 865>nul

:: your stuff here ::

rem restore chcp
chcp %cp%>nul
```

---

```
Code page: Country/region or language

437      : United States
850      : Multilingual (Latin I)
852      : Slavic (Latin II)
855      : Cyrillic (Russian)
857      : Turkish
860      : Portuguese
861      : Icelandic
863      : Canadian-French
865      : Nordic
866      : Russian
869      : Modern Greek
```

[a complete Code Page Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For further reading about that bug http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/03/08/389527.aspx